# Changing direction of a list on alternate rows

Tags: jquery, css, list, jquery-masonry

I'm using [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to help deal with laying out a list responsively. It works but the problem is I've been tasked with keeping the list in a very specific order. On the page there are always two related blocks - I've labelled them by colour here to visualise:

[image]

This works fine for resolutions that allow even numbers of blocks together. The problem is resolutions when there are an odd number of blocks on the page - the blocks must stay close to each other and I've been asked to make a 'snaking' pattern on odd rows so it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the list order essentially goes backwards for the alternate row.

The code looks like this:

```
<div id="block_holder">

        <a class="square_block" href="#">
            <div class="content_block client_block">
                <font color="red">1</font>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="square_block" href="#">
            <div class="content_block client_block">
                <font color="red">2</font>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="square_block" href="#">
            <div class="content_block client_block">
                <font color="blue">1</font>
            </div>
        </a>
         <a class="square_block" href="#">
            <div class="content_block client_block">
                <font color="blue">2</font>
            </div>
        </a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#block_holder').masonry({
                columnWidth: 238,
                gutter: 25,
                itemSelector: '.square_block'
        });
});
</script>
```

As you can see, there's nothing inherently linking the blocks together. I could probably use an ordered list or unordered list, but I still have no idea how I could get the list to 'reverse' at certain screen sizes. I guess this is something about Masonry I'd have to edit, but I have no idea where to even begin. Has anyone ever had to order a list like this before or have any pointers about how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% happy with the organization of this, but it achieves the objective:

http://jsfiddle.net/SF8W6/2/

The portion you might be most interested in:

```
function reorderItems(){
    var $items = $holder.find(options.itemSelector);
    $items.each(function(i,item){
        var remain = i%6;
        if(remain==2){
            $tempWrap = $('<div class="tempWrap"></div>');
            $(item).after($tempWrap);
        }

        if(remain > 2){
            $(item).detach().prependTo($tempWrap);
        }
    });

    $(".tempWrap").each(function(){
        $(this).find(options.itemSelector).first().unwrap();
    }).remove();

    triggerReset = true;
}
```

Don't know if there's an obviously better way to re-order a series of elements using jQuery, but I basically add a temporary wrapping div `$tempWrap` into the dom after every 3rd item, and populate it with the next 3 items in their reverse order (notice the use of `.prependTo()`), and then I get rid of the `$tempWrap` container with `.unwrap()`.

**Note!**

This will only work when you have a number of `.square_block` items that are a multiple of **3** (in your case, multiple of **6**, since everything is in  "1-2" pairs). If you only had 2 pairs (for example), that 4th block will be aligned to the left instead of below it's corresponding #1 block.

Comment: Thanks very much for this code, I would have been absolutely lost without it. Works perfectly, would upvote more than once if I could!

Comment: How would I alter this to work with 4 blocks per row? I feel like this should be an immediate and obvious change but unfortunately maths is not a strong point of mine. I guess it's to do with fiddling with the remain value but I can't quite get the right values.

Comment: do you mean 4 or 5? with 4 per row, you should be fine, since its an even number...